# SQL Server Hexadecimal data type

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm looking for a datatype in SQL Server that stores data as hexadecimal rather than int, but can't find anything similar. Surely there is a hexadecimal datatype?

Comment: You do know that an int is stored in binary, and it just happens that you manipulate it in decimal because it is handy? It doesn't matter how the storage is done. Just use int and manipulate it as you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Store it as an `INT` and use the `HEX()` function to convert it.

There's no native storage for hexadecimal in SQL Server.

EDIT:

You can also store hex data as `VARBINARY`, but there is still a conversion required, and there are data integrity issues with that method as well.

Comment: Actually you have another option too...editing my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for that, but instead of using HEX I've had to use convert(varbinary(4),33948700) as it doesn't seem to be available in MSSQL2000